# Cypress testing drag with mouse events not working

Tags: angular, testing, mouseevent, cypress, e2e-testing

Following the documentation https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#Mouse-Events I am trying to test the behavior of my app, where I draw a square by right clicking and dragging the mouse. In my original code I use mouse events and then in testing it I tried this:

```
  it.('should something.....', () => {
     cy.get('.container')
       .trigger('mousedown', 100, 100, { button: 2, force: true })
       .trigger('mousemove', 150, 200, { button: 2, force: true })
       .trigger('mouseup')
  });
```

But nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem as you.

The following code solved my problem:

```
it('Drag And Drop button into area', () => {
       const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer
       cy.get('x').trigger('dragstart', {
           dataTransfer    
       })
       cy.get('y').trigger('drop', {
           dataTransfer
        })
    });
```